# HTML 3 divs inside a container and only middle div has infinite scrolling

Tags: html, css

Image the following scenario:

```
<div class="header">Menu</div>  

<div class="container">  <!-- bootstrap 940px -->
  <div class="left-column">LEFT</div>
  <div class="center-column">CENTER (infinite scrolling)</div>
  <div class="right-column">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the HEADER always on the TOP so I use

```
.header {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

And that works well.

Now I need the left and right column to be fixed and the middle one to scroll, all happening within the container.

All the samples I see online show me a left column that uses position absolute but when I do that, the column appears outside the parent container that has width 940px

Here is the **[JSFiddle]**[1](http://jsfiddle.net/9n9cwe1x/2/) here !!

The Goal is to have:
1) The **RED** Div always **FIXED TOP**
2) The **BLUE** Div **NOT** Scrolling
3) The **GREEN** Div **NOT** Scrolling
4) The **ORANGE** Div ...**Infinite Scrolling**

Why is this not working ??

Comment: position:relative on the parent?

Comment: let me try a quick sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `position: relative;` in CSS on `.container element;`

```
.container { position: relative; }
```

**EDIT**

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n9cwe1x/3/)

**EDIT 2**

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ojm3937d/2/)

Comment: Should the middle column be aligned left?

Comment: @SDDeveloper see updated answer, don't know what do You meen by "not scroll"

Comment: In Facebook Timeline ...you can do infinite scrolling in the middle div but the right side stay up and does not scroll.

Comment: Every Div seems to be scrolling up. Ideally is for all DIVS (minus the CENTER one) should remain there. Not sure if it's the height 10000px. Does it scroll on your end?

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/xhLdxjn5/1/

```
.container { position: relative; }
```

Comment: Your solution (updated here) http://jsfiddle.net/xhLdxjn5/2/ has the scrolling occurring inside the div. I wanted something with infinite scrolling, a bit like Facebook. The scroll-bar should appear at the browser level, not at the div level.

Comment: facebook has a 3 column layout where the middle section is just infinity long and the left and right are fixed heights

http://jsfiddle.net/xhLdxjn5/4/